# Eclipse Not Showing Errors Or Running New Code

Tags: java, eclipse

So, I am pretty new to Eclipse, and I have been developing my first ever game with Java. I was working on my game for a long time, but when I shut down my computer,  Eclipse was blank after being opened.

Even after I tried to "Switch Workspace" nothing happened. So, I just created another Java project and imported all the classes, and that ended up working.

However, Eclipse began acting strangely after I did this.

First off, there were no errors at all on the screen, even when I purposely typed something incorrectly. I did a bit of research and tried to take all the steps that other people took to fix this problem, but there are still no errors on the screen.

Another thing is that when I change something in my code, it shows in the code, but the new code doesn't run. Only the previous version of the code will run.

Can somebody help me out please, because I do not know what to do?

Comment: Start by completely removing and reinstalling Eclipse

Comment: Will all my code save? I've been working on this for weeks now...

Comment: Your code is independent of Eclipse.  However, before you do anything get an account on GitHub or BitBucket, learn to use git, and make sure your code is checked in.

Comment: Your code is independent of which IDE you use. Figure out where your code is stored(folder) and attach it to the new install.

Comment: there are no relation between your IDE and your code, If you want to make your code safe, use github or svn, or just zip it and put it in another place if you afraid to lose it

Comment: Looks to me you disabled automatic project building in Project menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some commenters said that your code is independent of Eclipse. Well, that is not completely true: Eclipse stores some **metadata files and folders** into your project's directory:

- `.project` file and `.settings` folder: In every project.
- `.classpath` file: Just in every Java project.

Check if such files and folders are within your project's root directory.

If not, thay must have been missed for some reason. Then, you must do some configuration within Eclipse: Open your project, open the project's contextual menu, and select configure > convert to faceted form > select Java.

If the "convert to faceted form" option is not present in the context menu, open instead the "properties" option within the context menu and then "project facets", and select "Java".

This change has immediate effect, and should be enough for Eclipse to set the necessary metadata for a Java project.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have looked through both the "configure" and "properties" option and I was unable to find anything about a 'facet.' Do you know what my problem could be?

Comment: Well, what I did is I created yet another Java project and imported all the classes into it. But this time, I made sure to include ".project" and ".settings" files in my new project, and it worked. So thanks!

Comment: That's what I would have suggested you. Congratulations!